# Why is Json from API not rendering on the Table

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-table

So I wanted to play with ReactTable this evening to get information from an API and display on the table.
This is the PHP crafted REST API https://librational-`talker.000webhostapp.com/peopleBase/employee_informationAPI.php so now I want it to load the data from componentDidmount() it should populate the Table and show all the data on the table

I have this as an Empty table

[image: 2552.png]

when I run the API I get this

[image: jam3.png]

I wonder why it's not showing inside the Table.

My code is looking like this

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import ReactTable from "react-table"; 
import 'react-table/react-table.css'

export default class HomePage extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          users: [],
          loading:true
        }
      }

      async getUsersData(){
        const res = await axios.get('https://librational-talker.000webhostapp.com/peopleBase/employee_informationAPI.php')
        console.log(res.data)
        this.setState({loading:false, users: res.data})
      }
      componentDidMount(){
        this.getUsersData()
      }

    render() {

        const columns = [{  
            Header: 'ID',  
            accessor: 'ID',
           }
           ,{  
            Header: 'Firstname',  
            accessor: 'Firstname' ,
            }
           
           ,{  
           Header: 'Lastname',  
           accessor: 'Lastname' ,
           }
           ,{  
           Header: 'Gender',  
           accessor: 'Gender',
           },
           {  
            Header: 'DOB',  
            accessor: 'Date_of_birth',
            },
            {  
              Header: 'Email',  
              accessor: 'Email',
              },
              {  
            Header: 'Telephone',  
             accessor: 'Telephone',
            },
            {
                Header: 'NationalIDNumber',  
                accessor: 'NationalIDNumber',
            },
            {
                Header: 'PassportNumber',  
                accessor: 'PassportNumber',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Salary',  
                accessor: 'Salary',
            },
        ]

        return (
            <ReactTable  
            data={this.state.users}  
            columns={columns}  
         />
           );
    }

}
```

Is there something I appear to be missing here or not doing correctly? Please I need help. Very new to this.

**Edit**

Crosschecking, I saw this

[image: 805405.png]

So i have enabled the CORS from the Webhosting. But its still not Pulling the data and displaying the info on the Table.

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is because of your endpoint `https://librational-talker.000webhostapp.com/peopleBase/employee_informationAPI.php' you are trying to read a PHP file in as an object. Essentially this is the results of the PHP.

You need to create a constant for your API path and handle the data to format it correctly. something like this.

```
const API_PATH = https://librational-talker.000webhostapp.com/peopleBase/employee_informationAPI.php


 getUsersData = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios({
    method: 'users',
    url: `${API_PATH}`,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    data: this.state
  })
    .then(result => {
       this.setState({ loading: false, users: res.data });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
};
```

Might need some tweaking but hopefully this gets you in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks Checking , i saw the Error on CORS. Please see edits

Comment: You most likely need to add something to this to you path input                       
 headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}

Comment: Kindly explain, where do I add the access-header?

Comment: I have added that to the Webhosting I used. It returns in the console in the Browser. But to return in the code is a no no. I dont see it in reactTable.

Comment: Here I threw this together  this does not need the headers response using the lifecycle method.                                                                           
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-axios-api-yi94d7?file=style.css

Comment: It will get the data on the page you should be able to import it into your table component now

Comment: thanks , i got it to work. i made a mistake with the Datasource, correcting it works fine

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late would you mind sharing your code so when others running into this challenge happen they can see how to overcome it please thanks!

Answer (score -1):

So the steps i took to get it to work. Hopefully this would help a newbie someday.

1.) I logged on to 000webhost where I have the API hosted , and in the .htaccess file I added this to it

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

2.) Then Going thru my code again , I discovered I did not add the correct datasource. It was meant to be

```
return (
    <ReactTable  
    data={this.state.users}  
    columns={columns}  
 />
   );
```

And not

```
return (
    <ReactTable  
    data={this.state.data}  
    columns={columns}  
 />
   );
```

As early put. Enabling Cross Origin Resource sharing, turned out to be the main challenge. I am happy I was able to resolve it.

Thanks everyone.